# Solve $4x^2-4x-1=0\quad$. I get $\frac{1}{2}$ only, text book also shows $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to solve:

$4x^2-4x-1=0$

Using the quadratic formula:

$$\frac{4\pm\sqrt{-4^2-4(4)(-1)}}{2(4)}$$

$$\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-16}}{8}$$

$$\frac{4\pm0}{8}$$

So, my solution is $\frac{1}{2}$.

However, my textbook provided solution is both $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Where did this $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ come from?

Comment: $-4\cdot (4)(-1)=16$ not $-16$

Comment: Since some folk suggesting the textbook might be incorrect, here's the link to the textbook chapter I'm looking at. The particular exercise is 6th from the bottom of the page: https://cnx.org/contents/E6wQevFf@11.1:uIjtHMfW@8/Linear-Inequalities-and-Absolute-Value-Inequalities

Comment: Yeah, the discriminant is wrong @Allawonder

Comment: As Sheve pointed out, the way you multiplied out the terms in the radical is incorrect. Additionally, the textbook's solutions are $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. The two terms are not themselves separate solutions.

Comment: WolframAlpha is a good tool to check your answers (it will not give you solutions, usually), specially for simple problems when yours doesn't match with the textbook's s.a. in this case. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E2-4x-1

Comment: Thanks for the tip @LuizCordeiro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discriminant should instead be $$(-4)^2-4(4)(-1)=4^2+4^2=2(4^2)=32.$$

Answer (score 3):

So
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{(-4)^2-4(4)(-1)}}{8} \\
&=\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{(16-4(4)(-1)}}{8} \\
&= \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{32}}{8}\\
&=\frac{4 \pm 2\sqrt{8}}{8}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You're mis-reading the answer it's

$$\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$

So the two answers are

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\mbox{ and } \frac{1}{2} -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$

As others have said, the discriminant in your quadratic formula should be $\sqrt{32} = 4\sqrt{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

You incorrectly calculated the discriminant inside the root, which should be

$$ (-4)^{2} - 4(4)(-1) = 16 - 16(-1) = 16 + 16 = 32$$

Thus, the (unsimplified) solution should be

$$ \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{32}}{8} $$

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the Quadratic formula, let's illustrate the solution by completing the square:

$$ 4 (x^{2} - x + \hskip 12pt ) = 1$$

$$ 4 (x^{2} - x + \frac{1}{4} ) = 1 + 4\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)   $$

$$ 4 \left(x - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} = 2$$

$$ \left(x - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$ x - \frac{1}{2} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} $$

$$ x = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$